# What are supported device attributes on iOS during enrollment phase?

Tags: ios, profile, mdm, ota, over-the-air

I'm installing configuration profile using over-the-air (OTA) enrollment. What are supported device attributes on iOS during first phase payload?
I'm sending sth like:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Challenge</key>
            <string>challenge</string>

            <key>DeviceAttributes</key>
            <array>
                <string>UDID</string>
                <string>DEVICE_NAME</string>
                <string>VERSION</string>
                <string>PRODUCT</string>
                <string>MAC_ADDRESS_EN0</string>
                <string>IMEI</string>
                <string>ICCID</string>
            </array>

            <key>URL</key>
            <string>https://my-profile-server</string>
        </dict>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>Enter device into the encrypted profile service</string>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.xxx.mobileconfig.profile-service</string>
        <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
        <string>XXX</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>1a21d4dd-6723-45c5-a184-c3fe0075db14</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Is there any more attribute that I can get from the device in this payload? For example serial number? Is there any official list of possible attributes?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not found an official list, however, I know you can get the following device attributes during the OTA enrollment phase:

- DEVICE_NAME
- UDID
- IMEI
- MEID
- SERIAL
- VERSION
- PRODUCT

Answer (score 3):

Important note: Newer versions of iOS support fewer and fewer properties. iOS 6 pretty much only does DEVICE_NAME, UDID and VERSION.

Comment: Trying on iOS6.1, you can still get SERIAL and PRODUCT as well

Comment: @goldmine: And no longer DEVICE_NAME, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

- UDID
- VERSION
- PRODUCT (ie. iPhone1,1 or iPod2,1)
- MAC_ADDRESS_EN0 (WiFi MAC address)
- DEVICE_NAME (given device name "iPhone")
- IMEI (Only on iPhones)
- ICCID (Only on iPhones)

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/CompanionFiles.zip

Answer (score 0):

I will add that VERSION is not the string '8.3' (eg), but rather the internal build id of the OS. '8.3' may have more than one such VERSION (probably minor changes that are still considered same source tree.)

There are some services online that offer IPSW downloads, and also provide the internal name for lookup.

Visit: https://api.ipsw.me/v2.1/firmwares.json for a list of build ids.